# TypeError while appedning dictionaries to another dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have several functions that return a dictionary.

Lets say `funcA` returns : `{'cat': 2, 'dog': 3, 'cAt': 1}`

And `funcB` returns `{'cat': 1, 'dog': 1, 'cAt': 1, 'man' : 1}`

I tried appending them into `new_dict = {}` using `Counter`

So I would ultimatly get that

```
 new_dict = `{'cat': 3, 'dog': 4, 'cAt': 2, 'man' : 1}`
```

(I want to append the keys and sum the values into each unique key)

So for each funct call I did:

```
new_dict += Counter(func())
```

But then I got that each function over - rided the previous function call, or I got in some cases a Type error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'Counter'
```

How can I execute it properly?

Comment: To get more direct feedback, consider posting your complete func. or at least the relevant part of it. With couple of line suggesting what you tried is a good start but does not necessarily gives the complete picture of your method.

Comment: @Ani Can we just assume that these functions function 'stupidly' and just return dictionaries? because each function is kinda complicated while it works completly fine. the part when I want to combine each product of the functions is the problematic one.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `new_dict` as a `Counter` object instead of a dict so that it would use the `Counter.__iadd__` method to perform the desired updates to counts with `new_dict += Counter(func())`:

```
new_dict = Counter()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
new_dict = Counter(funcA()) + Counter(funcB())
```

Note that new_dict will be a Counter object.  You can convert it back to a dictionary if that's not what you need.